# Express get picture and send to imgur

Tags: express, request, axios, multipart, body-parser

I'm using express with nodejs,
and i would like to use imgur to host pictures.
I have my access token, and I need to request this endpoint : "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload"
with the header : `headers: {'Authorization': "bearer " + config.access_token_imgur, 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}` with the given picture.

When it comes to do it, the first problem is handling the picture : this is multipart and bodyparser can't.
I tried multer, but it's always saving the picture, and i only want to get it, and post it to the endpoint, so,
my goals is :

```
    router.post("/upload",upload.single('file'), async (req,res)=>{ 
  if(req.file){
    var headers = {
        headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${config.access_token_imgur}`, 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    };
    var formData = new FormData();
    //formData.append("image", req.file);
    axios.post('https://api.imgur.com/3/upload', formData, headers).then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.body);
        console.log(res.data);
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
    })

    //must get a picture from the parameters (how to handle ? )
    //send it to https://api.imgur.com/3/upload with headers with post method
    //handle response
  }else{
      res.status(500).json({success: false})
  }
```

})

As you can see, i tried with multer, but i think this is not the good answer:
How to handle the picture without saving ? (multipart), and send it to the endpoint ? (axios, request,...)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did :

```
 router.post('/upload', (req, res, next)=> { //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534589/receiving-uploading-file-too-fast-error-from-imgur-api --> must verify file type
    var busboy = new Busboy({ 
      headers: req.headers,
      limits: {
        fileSize: 1000000 * 200, //limit to 200mb because imgur's limit, and 1gb is buffer's limit --> must pass on aws s3 if needed - limit in byte
        files: 1,
      }
    });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        if(fieldname == 'image') {
            // the buffer
            file.fileRead = []; //------------need convert to gif !!----------- ------------------------------------------------
            file.on('data', function(data) {
                // add to the buffer as data comes in
                this.fileRead.push(data);
            });
            file.on('limit', ()=>{
              res.status(500).json({success: false, message: "file too big ! Musn't cross the line of 200mo ! We'll soon reduce this limit"})
            })
            file.on('end', function() {
                // create a buffer
                var finalBuffer = Buffer.concat(this.fileRead); 
                upload = uploadpicture(finalBuffer, mimetype).then((response)=>{ //success request
                  console.log(response);
                  res.status(200).json({success: true, message: "Successfully uploaded !", url: response.data.link});
                },(err)=>{ //error
                  console.log(err);
                  res.status(500).json({success: false, message: "Error happenned while uploading !"});
                }).catch((err)=>{
                  console.log(err);
                  res.status(500).json({success: false, message: "Error happenned while uploading !"});
                });
            })
        }
    });
/*    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {
        console.log('field');
    });*/
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        //busboy finished
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that bodyParser won't help you with multipart data.

### Solution 1:

You can still use multer for processing, but with different storage engine. For example you can use [MemoryStorage](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#memorystorage) which will simply cache the files being processed in memory, without actually writing them to disk.

### Solution 2:

If you want to skip image processing at all, you can forward the request to the 3-rd party service with something like this code:

```
const request = require('request')
...

router.post('/upload', (req,res, next) => { 
  const forwardReqConfig = {
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `bearer ${config.access_token_imgur}`,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  };
  req.pipe(request.post(forwardReqConfig)).pipe(res)
})
```

Since express [req](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) object inherits from nodejs [request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) object it is also a stream. The same applies for res object as well. You can pipe req stream into the stream created by the [request lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming) and then pipe back the response from the 3-rd party service into res of your API.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your answer ;) I'm trying to use your code, but when working, I receive "Malformed auth header" with status 403. So I tried to modify the b of "bearer" to "Bearer", and I get status 400 with no response body, any idea ? Thanks ^^

Comment: According to the [docs](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#authorization-and-oauth) `Bearer` seems to be the one accepted by imgur.
In your case I think [this](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#a94d108b-d6e3-4e68-9521-47ea79501c85) could be helpful. The `/3/upload` endpoint expects Client-ID instead of bearer token, so you can try with that.